# HTML layout issue using display:table

Tags: css, html, tablelayout

I am trying to use `display:table, table-row` to get a final output as below. The blue box should be resizable and the red box should have fixed height.

[image]

To start a jsbin is [here](http://jsbin.com/ikepif/1/edit).

I am looking for a css solution. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "resizeable?" Should it grow to fit content?

Comment: It should take the rest of the vertical space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work with **display:table** . Write like this:

```
#wrapper {height:250px; width:200px; border:3px solid gray; display:table;}
  #one {height:100px; background-color:red;display: table-row;}
  #two {background-color:blue;display: table-row;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jYvK2/

Comment: It is working. But when we do not put any text inside it does not work. However that is not my problem so I am accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: that's why i add text on it because i saw this type of error in others elements also.